# How do I create a Python Decimal object from C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, boost-python

...or any Python object that exists in an importable library. I have found PyDateTime_* functions in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/datetime.html) for creating objects from the datetime module, but I can't find anything to do with the python decimal module. Is this possible?

Looking for a Boost.Python way if there is one, but the native API's will suffice if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Boost.Python that would be something like

```
bp::object decimal = bp::import("decimal").attr("Decimal");
bp::object decimal_obj = decimal(1, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Should be straightforward enough.  Although untested, something like the following should work:

```
PyObject * decimal_mod = PyImport_ImportModule("decimal");
assert(decimal_mod);
PyObject * decimal_ctor = PyObject_GetAttrString(decimal_mod, "Decimal");
assert(decimal_ctor);
PyObject * four = PyObject_CallFunction(decimal_ctor, "i", 4);
assert(four);
```

Do keep in mind that all three `PyObject *` references here should be decreffed (using `Py_DECREF()`) once you are done with them.  Also, I use `assert()` here for pedagogical purposes.  Actual code should have real error handling.

Also, I use the raw Python/C API here.  I've never used boost-python, so I don't know what differences exist, if any.

Comment: i've accepted the other answer as i've tested it and it works (although i tagged boost-python in my question i didn't actually state it so i'll edit my question now). thanks for answering though, i'm sure this will help anybody who finds this page that doesn't want the boost dependency.